# How to make PHP cookies global in every page

Tags: php, cookies

i'm using cookies for my new website but i came across with this problem:
if i set a cookie with my script on

> server.dom/scripts/addcookie.php

it will save my cookie but it will not be available on

> server.dom/index.php

I believe that the problem i caused by the path.
Any idea how to make it global?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `setcookie()`, give `/` as path parameter .

```
setcookie( $name, $value, $expire, '/');
                                    ^- the entire domain will share the cookie
```

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation](http://php.net/setcookie):

> ```
> bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )
> ```
>
> path
>   The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If
>   set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If
>   set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/
>   directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. The
>   default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set
>   in.

So set the 4th agument to `setcookie` to `'/'`